# Add marker of my location in Google Map with other markers from Wordpress API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I´m searching for the right way to add my location in a map. My map shows markers from events.

A function to add a marker and zoom the map to level 12 should start if a user clicks the button ('Where I am?').

Can anybody help me with this?

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 10.5),
    zoom: 6
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}
```

[View on codepen](https://codepen.io/hobboh/pen/yLLeRpy)

Comment: Is your wordpress site secure (served over https)?  Your codepen doesn't work.  Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself** (preferably a working StackOverflow code snippet that demonstrates the issue)

Comment: The button worked and fired the function for locate the user but how I can add my markers? Here is my https Test Site [Test Site](https://kabarett-aus-bayern.de)

Answer (score 0):

A function like the below will return the coordinates of the user's location in a { lat, lng } object:

```
function getCurrentLocation() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) reject(new Error('Get User Location error'));
    else {
      return Promise.resolve(
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          let currentCoordinates = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude,
          };
          resolve(currentCoordinates);
        }),
      );
    }
  });
}
```

The function calls the browser's `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function which returns the coordinates of the user if it is enabled. The function is asynchronous (i.e. will take some time to run and your code will have to wait for the operation to complete) so should be called like the following (note the `async` and `await` keywords):

```
function async callingFunction() {
  let userLocationCoords = await getCurrentLocation()
  let userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: userLocationCoords,
      map: map,
    });
  ...
}
```

This causes the code to 'wait' for the getCurrenLocation() function to finish running before moving on.

Note that this will not work if the connection is http rather than https (at least in Chrome), but it should work in your Codepen, which is https. It will also give a prompt to the user to allow the website to access their location which they must accept in order for the function to work.

Once you have the user's coordinates you can add a marker to the map by using `new google.maps.Marker()` and supplying it with the { lat, lng } coordinates of the marker and the map object you want to add it to as per the code above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The button worked and fired the function for locate the user but how I can add my markers? 
[Test Site](https://kabarett-aus-bayern.de)

Comment: I've added the code for adding a marker to the above, which is similar to how you are adding your existing markers to the map. The official Google Maps API docs are a great place to look for examples and more info. E.g. https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#introduction